# Should I user 'row' class as parent/child or on the 'header/main' elements?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and trying to structure my bootstrap classes correctly but I'm confused as to what to do when it comes to 'header' and 'main' html5 elements, as well as other native html elements.  Where should I use rows in relation to these elements?  Should I just put the row class on them?  Nested inside them?  Or should these elements each have a row tag as a parent?  Or is there just no right or wrong way to do this?  I feel like bootstrap is sort of set up like:

```
container(s)
  row(s)
    col(s)
      row(s)
         col(s)
            ...etc
```

But the built-in html elements seem to sort of cut into that like two different paradigms butting heads and I don't know what's expected of me as a developer and how to handle that.  When I look online I see everybody doing everything sort of randomly and haven't been able to find any specific guidelines for how to correctly structure the bootstrap class paradigm within the semantic html5 naming paradigm.

I tried looking into the documentation and surprisingly didn't find anything and I have found nobody discussing this issue online.  Is there any logical rule to follow in this regard or is it just random?

Answer (score 4):

The  element is used to contain the header of your website. You can use this element and then use the bootstrap rows, containers, etc inside of your  element. So for example

```
<header>
    <h1>Title of my site here</h1>
</header>
```

or

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               My Header Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

You can also reference: http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

There really is no wrong way to do it. Its just a preference.

Answer (score 1):

> **Some Bootstrap grid system rules:**
>
> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or    .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be    immediate children of rows
> - Predefined classes like .row and .col-sm-4 are available for quickly    making grid layouts
> - Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding.    That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via
>     negative margin on .rows
> - Grid columns are created by specifying the number of 12 available    columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use
>     three .col-sm-4

Here the full info: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Here an snippet example to illustrate:

```css
.show-grid [class^="col-"]{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  background-color: #EEE;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-8">.col-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-8">.col-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-6</div>
</div>
```

As Joe said "There really is no wrong way to do it. Its just a preference." but i recommend you to separate the `row` from others content like this:

```
//no
<div class="something row">
    ...
</div>

//yes
<div class="something">
    <div class="row">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

because `row` has `margin: 0 -15px` so if you want to set a different `margin` to `something` you will overwrite the `row` margin.